# USB FPGA Firmware ISP1362: Enumeration, Empty OUT Packet

Tags: usb, enumeration, fpga, firmware

I am writing firmware to interface an FPGA to Mat-Lab for data acquisition and control.  The setup thus far is FPGA (DE2-115) -> ISP 1362 -> PC (Windows).  I am using a generic "USB View" program to view the device descriptors.

I've hit a wall.  The USB Host resets my device, then sends an 8-byte "Get Descriptor" request.  I fill the IN EP with 18 bytes and validate it.  Some 20? microseconds later the ISP1362 flags an interrupt and the status of the IN EP is that it is empty (data sent, right?).  Then some more microseconds later there is zero length packet in the OUT EP.  I then clear the OUT EP.  AFter about 220 microseconds the host then resets my device again.  What does that darn zero length packet mean?

Summarize: Receive Bus Reset, Receive Get Descriptor, Send Description, Receive Empty Packet, Receive Bus Reset.

Also, is there a program that will let me look at the raw data interaction of this?  I want to see what the host (PC) sees.

```
bLength             =   8'h12        ;
bDescriptorType     =   8'h01        ;
bcdUSB              =   16'h0200     ;
bDeviceClass        =   8'h00        ;
bDeviceSubClass     =   8'h00        ;
bDeviceProtocol     =   8'h00        ;
bMaxPacketSize0     =   8'h40        ;
idVendor            =   16'h067B     ;
idProduct           =   16'h2303     ;
bcdDevice           =   16'h0400     ;
iManufacturer       =   8'h01        ;
iProduct            =   8'h02        ;
iSerialNumber       =   8'h00        ;
bNumConfigs         =   8'h01        ;
```

Comment: Have you looked at this code: http://mzakharo.github.io/usb-de2-fpga/ They are doing almost the same as you do.

Comment: Yes.  I'm aware of him and his code.  I've contacted him but he is too busy to help me.  USBlyzer and USBtrace aren't of much help to me either.

Comment: What is the value of your descriptor, can you share it here?

Comment: I've added the descriptor to the original post.

Comment: Try to use USBCap http://desowin.org/usbpcap it makes it easier to analyze your communication, then you can use the wireshark to analyze the data. You have the instructions here : http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is the handshake (i.e. Zero-Length Packet) back from the Host during the status stage.

After you send the 18-byte descriptor the Host sends an ACK back to your device.  This ACK generates an interrupt in the status register which you read and clear.  The data stage is finished and the status stage starts.  The Host sends an OUT token along with an empty packet (ZLP) to acknowledge the successful receipt of this data.  Your device sends an ACK back.  This ends the status stage.

Have a look at Control Transfers on this site:
http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb4.shtml

Notice how Control Transfers have the following format: SETUP -> DATA -> STATUS.  Read carefully the "The bigger picture" section where each stage is broken down into individual packets.